# Why the facebook iframe like button is not working ?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

Although it works offline, it isn't working online..this is the code used

`<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=125925834166578&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FBaradei.Presidency&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

And this is the webpage in which the like button at the bottom of the page isn't working...Please help! http://www.ali_lsheikh.0fees.net/baradei.html

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would try is to include all the necessary Open Graph tags. For example from my site [Candy Japan](http://www.candyjapan.com/):

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="297200003"/> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.candyjapan.com"/> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="candyjapan"/> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Candy Japan"/> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.candyjapan.com/static/logo.png"/>
```

Then also see that it passes the Facebook [url linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http://www.ali_lsheikh.0fees.net/baradei.html). Currently it is reporting some error about your page I have never seen before "blocked or is being accessed too frequently, so we're not fetching it.". Perhaps it will start fetching again later, so I would try linting again after a while.